# First attempt at a SVG parser

Tags: beginner, haskell, svg, parsec

I figured it's about time to jump into some Haskell, so here's a first attempt at an oddly specific SVG parser:

```
import System.Environment
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec 

parseFile fname = parseFromFile (manyTill (try tag) (try readEnd)) fname

tag = do manyTill anyChar . try $ lookAhead tagStart
         char '<'
         name <- many $ noneOf " "
         props <- tagContents
         char '>'
         junk
         return (name, props)

tagContents = do props <- manyTill property . try . lookAhead $ char '>'
                 junk
                 return props

property = do spaces
              name <- many1 $ noneOf "="
              string "=\""
              val <- manyTill anyChar $ char '"'
              junk
              return (name, val)

junk = optional . many $ oneOf "\n\r\t\\/"

readEnd = do optional $ string "</svg>" 
             junk
             eof
tagStart = do char '<'
              tagName

tagName = string "rect" 
          <|> string "polygon" 
          <|> string "polyline" 
          <|> string "circle" 
          <|> string "path" 
          <|> string "g" 
          <|> string "svg"
```

Before anyone asks, one of the objectives for this program (other than learning) is that it should accept invalid SVGs (for example, a partial SVG or one that has been saved as an `rtf`), which is why I'm making liberal use of `try`, and cherry-picking tags.

As implied by the title, this is my first non-tutorial attempt at Haskell, so give me all the style pointers you can muster (and highlight anything that signals a broken understanding on my part).

I'd also appreciate pointers on how to cherry-pick properties (and not just tags). I've tried writing `property` as

```
property = do manyTill anyChar . try $ lookAhead tagName
              name <- many1 $ noneOf "="
              string "=\""
              val <- manyTill anyChar $ char '"'
              junk
              return (name, val)
```

and defining `propName` as

```
propName = string "points" 
           <|> string "x" 
           <|> string "y" 
           <|> string "r" 
           <|> string "d" 
           <|> string "cx" 
           <|> string "cy" 
           <|> string "width" 
           <|> string "height" 
           <|> string "transform"
```

This seems like it should work since it's basically how I got `tag` jumping to the next desired tag, but it gives me unexpected input errors.

---

Edit The Second:

```
import System.Environment
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec 

type TagName = String
type Property = (PropName, Value)
type PropName = String
type Value = String

parseFile fname = parseFromFile (manyTill (try tag) (try readEnd)) fname

tag :: GenParser Char st (TagName, [Property])
tag = do manyTill anyChar . try $ lookAhead tagStart
         name <- tagStart
         props <- tagContents
         char '>'
         junk
         return (name, props)

tagContents :: GenParser Char st [Property]
tagContents = do props <- manyTill property . try . lookAhead $ char '>'
                 junk
                 return props

property :: GenParser Char st (PropName, Value)
property = do manyTill anyChar . try $ lookAhead propName
              name <- many1 $ noneOf "="
              string "=\""
              val <- manyTill anyChar $ char '"'
              junk
              return (name, val)

junk = many $ oneOf "\n\r\t\\/{} "

tagStart :: GenParser Char st TagName
tagStart = do char '<'
              name <- tagName
              return name

readEnd = do optional $ string "</svg>" 
             junk
             eof

tagName = oneStringOf ["rect", "polygon", "polyline", "circle", "path", "g", "svg"]
propName = oneStringOf ["points", "x", "y", "r", "d", "cx", "cy", "width", "height", "transform"]

oneStringOf :: [String] -> GenParser Char st String
oneStringOf = choice . map (try . string)
```

- Added `try` to the definition of `oneStringOf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here are some things I noticed:

First of all, while the code seems easy enough to follow as it is, a couple of comments here and there certainly couldn't hurt.

---

```
tag = do manyTill anyChar . try $ lookAhead tagStart
         char '<'
         name <- many $ noneOf " "
```

It seems weird that you first use `tagStart` to find until where to match, but then don't use it to actually match the tag start.

---

```
junk = optional . many $ oneOf "\n\r\t\\/"
```

Since many can already match the empty string, making it optional doesn't change anything.

---

```
tagName = string "rect" 
          <|> string "polygon" 
          <|> string "polyline" 
          <|> string "circle" 
          <|> string "path" 
          <|> string "g" 
          <|> string "svg"
```

That looks a bit repetitive. I'd define a helper function which matches one of a list of strings:

```
-- Takes a list of strings and returns a Parser which matches any of those strings
oneStringOf = choice . map (try . string)

tagName = oneStringOf ["rect", "polygon", "polyline"] -- etc
```

By adding the `try` we also made it so that it actually works correctly now (thanks to Joey Adams for pointing out that fix).

---

As for why your alternative definition for `property` doesn't work: I'm not sure whether it's the only thing that keeps it from working, but one mistake is that you wrote `tagName` when you meant `propName`.